# Hover delay with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am trying to achieve a time delay during a hover effect for a dropdown menu. I am trying to use the setTimeout and the dropdown do work correctly on hover, but I don't get the delay. It happens just instantaneously. Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.dropdown-hover").hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
});

function hoverIn(){
    setTimeout(func1(this), 3000);
}

function hoverOut(){
    setTimeout(func2(this), 1000);
}

function func1(element) {
    $(element).find(".dropdown-menu-hover").css("display", "block");
}

function func2(element) {
    $(element).find(".dropdown-menu-hover").css("display", "none");
}
```

I am pretty new to jQuery and for some reason, I don't wish to use any external plugin such as http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html which is suggested in many similar questions. Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `setTimeout(func1(this), 3000);`, you're invoking the `func1` function immediately. It's the same thing as this:

```
func1(this);
setTimeout(undefined, 3000);
```

Instead, you want to pass `setTimeout` a new function which will run after the allotted time.

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
  func1(self);
}, 3000);
```

Or you can pass `this` as an extra parameter as Richard B shows.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Somehow setTimeout is not able to access 'this' (it is taken as window object instead of 'li'), so I did a workaround by storing it in a variable. Its working now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's default function `.delay` like this:

```
$('.a').hover(function () {
    $('.b').delay(2000).fadeIn(200);
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sukritchhabra/upkgtLyn/1

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to pass parameters to the function as follows:

```
setTimeout(func1, 3000,this);
```

as opposed to

```
setTimeout(func1(this), 3000);
```